# PHP, Как сделать переход на страницу товара на сайте?

Tags: php

Бд подключил, все товары из бд выводит на экран, при нажатии на товар меня перебрасывает localhost/product/1, но там просто Internal Server Error, а если просто localhost/product, то откроет но, это будет просто страница products.php т.е пустая, мне надо сделать так, чтоб при нажатии, был переход на страницу товара и именно этого товара на который нажму, я очень много искал в интернете решения и на ютубе смотрел, не смог найти, может тут кто поможет, заранее спасибо)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,name,price,images,filter FROM `goods`",$db);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

do{
    echo '<li class="mix '.$row['filter'].' check1 radio2 option3 bott" style="margin-left: 10px;">
    <a href="/products/'.$row['id'].'"><b class="podr wow flipInX">Подробнее</b></a>
    <<b class="name wow flipInX">'.$row['name'].'</b>
    <b class="price wow flipInX">'.$row['price'].'₽</b>
    <img src='.$row['images'].' alt="Image 1"></li>';
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
} ?>
```

Comment: Код сюда вставлять надо __текстом__, а не скриншотами.

Comment: Всё добавил код!

Comment: А маршрут вы как обрабатываете?

Comment: .htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ /&controller=$1&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NS,L]

Comment: Я про то как у вас он выводится, как вы получаете продукт для его обработки? Тут я так понимаю вы выводите ссылки на продукты

Comment: Я не особо понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду! скорее всего этого просто нету, я не знаю как сделать это, может вы знаете?

Comment: products.php покажите.

Comment: <?php 
include('header.php');
include_once('config.php');
?>
<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM goods", $db); 
if($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
?>
<section class="products">
 
</section>
<?php } ?>
<?php 
include('footer.php');
?>